# How do I get the second feature image in shopify?

Tags: shopify, liquid

How do I get the second feature image here?

{{ item.featured_image | product_img_url: 'grande' | img_tag }}

Thanks for any help,

Alexander Hein

Comment: second featured image or second image? There is only one featured image for images.

Answer (score 2):

To get the second image of the product you can use this code:-

```
{% for image in product.images limit:1 offset:1 %}
<img src="{{ image | img_url: "medium" }}" />
{% endfor %}
```